# Virus Logic - pseudo / PoC

Tags: logic, pseudocode

I am trying to get my head around this problem. Hopefully someone can help.

Imagine we have a program called `Confusion`;

```
Program confusion
if(Virus-Finder(Confusion) = false) then
   infect-executable
else
   halt
End program confusion
```

Obviously this is pseudo code, so won't run.

For any program `P`, we can run `Virus-Finder(P)` the result will be `True` if it is a virus, and `False` if it is not.

`infect-executable` is a module that scans the memory for executable programs and replicates the program `Confusion` in those executables.

We have no direction as to what `Virus-Finder` actually does, only that it returns `True` if the input is a virus, or `False` if it is not,.

Is it possible to determine if `Virus-Finder` can correctly decide whether `Confusion` is a virus or not? My initial thought is no, it cannot. But I cannot get my head around the logic.

Comment: I suspect any algorithm that tries to statically determine what some non-trivial program does is effectively equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: What you describe here is Fred Cohen's proof that computer virus detection is undecidable: See "Detection of Viruses" in https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~aprakash/eecs588/handouts/cohen-viruses.html

Answer (score 0):

What you say is not well defined, but supposing the following :
`Virus-finder(p)` returns `true` if `p` executes `infect-executable`

In that case, it is easy to prove that `Virus-finder(p)` is not decidable, and your pseudo-code does it exactly :
Suppose that `Virus-finder(p)` is decidable, so it always returns `true` (resp. `false`) if `p` executes (resp. does not execute) `infect-executable`. Then your pseudo-code shows that `Virus-finder` can not decide whether it is a virus or not.

As Barmar mentionned, such a reasoning is often a way to prove the undecidability of some problem, in particular the halting problem (the other well-known method is to reduce to an other undecidable problem).